# Unable to find Tensor data while using Tensorflow.js's tf.browser.fromPixels()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tensorflow, mern, tensorflow.js

```
    function trial(ss) {                            // ss is the image in base64 string
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = ss;
    image.onload = () => {
        let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image, 3);
        Promise.resolve(tensor).then(r => {
            console.log(tensor);
            dispatch(initializeImageTensor({tensor}));
        });
    }
}
```

When i call trial i pass it a image in base64 form which is then passed to Image().
But when i check the output of tensor i am unable to find the actual array of data:

[image]

Where is the actual array/tensor data stored and do i use normal `axios.post("URL", qs.stringify({tensor}))` to send it to my backend.
I'm using `@tensorflow/tfjs` not `tfjs-node`

Comment: Please do not post images of code/logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data of your tensor through `tensor.array()`, `tensor.buffer()` or `tensor.data()`.